# Force expell library for given div-structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph, jsplumb

Given a HTML structure like so:

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div class="group group-normal" id="1">hello world</div>
    <div class="group group-infiltrated" id="2">whats up dogue</div>
</div>
```

I currently use jsPlumb to create a graph from that structure:

```
$(function() {

    jsPlumb.Defaults.Container = $("div#canvas");

    jsPlumb.draggable($("div.group"), {
        containment: $("div#canvas")
    });

    var stateMachineConnector = {               
        connector: "Bezier",
        paintStyle: { lineWidth: 2, strokeStyle: "#056" },
        endpoint: "Blank",
        anchor: "Continuous",
        overlays:[ ["PlainArrow", { location: 1, width: 15, length: 12 } ]]
    };

    jsPlumb.connect({
        source: "1",
        target: "2"
    }, stateMachineConnector);
});
```

Which already gives me a nice, draggable graph:

[image: Simple-graph]

The problem is, that when initialising the graph, all the `div`s are in the upper left corner of the canvas. I learned that this is due that jsPlumb only provides functionality to layout a graph, but not to position it.

I then went on a scavenger hunt and found many useful libraries that deal with positioning, like springy, sigma and alike. The problem is: Most of the don't operate on divs, but rather on some (for me) instransparent SVG/Canvas object graph.

I like jsPlumb very much and would like to keep using it. The only thing I need from other libraries is the initial positioning of all the elements.

How can I make the elements be positioned more evenly over the space available, maybe even in a way that makes them arrange **the same way every time the graph is initialized**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the plugin for positioning DIV's which has connectivity: https://github.com/lndb/jsPlumb_Liviz.js
Basically the plugin is derived from **[graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)** js library.

You need to pass the connectivity information to the library through a textarea(id=dot-src). So whenever you establish a connection, store the connectivity info in a string and later pass it to the Liviz library for positioning it.

```
str='digraph MyGraph {'; // This string will be set to the textarea at the end.

// Whenever connection is created update the string.
jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(ci) {
            console.log($('#'+ci.sourceId).data("prop").dn+"->"+$('#'+ci.targetId).data("prop").dn);
            str+=ci.sourceId+"->"+ci.targetId+";";
});

// At the end set the string and call Liviz function
$('#dot-src').text(str+"}"); // Set the string
w_launch(); // call the library to position the DIV's based on connectivity.
```

You can explore **[graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)** for different types of options to customise positioning.

Comment: I also came across this one, but I didnt find any information on how to actuall include it. What javascript files to I need?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Include all the `script` tags from this html:https://github.com/lndb/jsPlumb_Liviz.js/blob/master/jsPlumbChar.htm#L461. At the end of the html file you will find the textarea contained with predefined connections. Instead you can make it empty and follow above code for dynamic construction of it. Remove the jQuery helper script(inside jsPlumb folder) and include your own.

Comment: OK greate, it seems to work - the only problem is, that the positioning is not contained within the `<div id="canvas">` - do you have an idea how to make that happen? Currently, it just positions the nodes all over the window

Comment: Inside Liviz.js folder open main.js. In 9th line change the `dot` layout to any other like `sfdp`, `neato`,etc. I would recommend you to try `neato` first.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka If you want to retain `dot` layout then you can modify the options such as `nodesep`, `ranksep`, etc. Refer:http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ranksep
Change the string as `str='digraph MyGraph {nodesep=0.5;ranksep=1.4;';`

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, but the problem remains: The nodes are positioned well outside the `<div>` they are originally in, so they are just positioned realtive to my window, which is really ugly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48475/discussion-between-pruthvi-bharadwaj-and-florian-peschka)